# Flutter cannot generate docs with dartdoc

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

I am not able to generate the documentation of the code by using the `dartdoc` tool located at `C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin`. This is what I do:

1. Go to the project dir `dir C:\Users\alber\Documents\progetto_fomet\fomet_app\lib`
2. Call the command `dartdoc`

It works because in `C:\Users\alber\Documents\progetto_fomet\fomet_app\lib\doc\api` I see the documentation but it doe NOT include the documentation of my code!

The tool generates the doc of dart like here

[image]

but it does NOT generate the doc of my app in flutter

[image]

In red you see the source of my app that is not being doc-generated in doc\api. What to do?

I am on Windows 10

Comment: Did you run just `dartdoc` or did you give it some arguments?  If you supplied arguments, what did arguments did you pass?  Also, your step 1 "Go to..." lists directory contents; it doesn't *go* there.  Did you mean `cd` instead?

Comment: Just run dartdoc from the main folder with NO arguments...

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this a lot.
Solved by the following steps using the PowerShell:

1. Installing CHOCOLATEY from https://chocolatey.org/install#individual
2. Activating dartdoc using `flutter pub global activate dartdoc`
3. Activating dhttpd using `flutter pub global activate dhttpd`
4. Generating the documentation `dartdoc` on the project folder
5. Viewing the generated files using `dhttpd --path doc/api`

Alternatively on macOS you can use `Homebrew` to install the `dartdoc` and `dhttpd`